# jQuery Date Picker: Select Weeks at a Time

Tags: jquery

I know that there are lots of jQuery date pickers available and I have looked through a number.  Essentially, I need a date picker that allows the user to select only entire weeks at a time.  The user is picking room reservations, which last for a week.  Therefore, I want the date picker to show such explicitly.

Before I modified a date picker, I figured I would see if anyone knew of a date picker that already does such.  Currently I am using Datepicker (http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html), but I don't mind using something else.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should help you out :)

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerSelectWeek.html

Answer (score 1):

As of HTML5 there is a new date (week) picker. Although it's not jQuery, it's extremely simple. Use

> type="week"

in the input field:

```
<input type="week">
```

Right now only [supported](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp) by Chrome, Opera and Safari. Might be worth having a look at?

Try a sample at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_week).